# Is Non-vegetarian Cheese halal

Tags: halal-haram, food

My question is specifically regarding Pesto I have been having for a few weeks, until last Friday when I noticed the words `Non vegetarian cheese`.

Please see this image:

[image: Please note the bottom of the label]

I am wondering whether to continue enjoying this product or to throw it away. Both the cheese mentioned in this product, Padano Cheese & Pecorino Romano Cheese appear to be milk based.

My question is, is this halal to consume or should I err on the side of caution & throw it away.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

It seems like (thanks to the answerer below) the product contains potentially one haram ingredient namely rennet. It is extracted from the stomach of animals.

> Traditional animal rennet is an enzyme derived from the stomachs of calves, lambs or goats before they consume anything but milk.  Vegetable rennet is obtained from a type of mold (Mucur Miehei). However, even though it is derived from mold, there is no mold contained in the final product. It is an equivalent chymosin product which works equally well but is not animal derived.

I've skimmed the following articles for something haram based on the ingredients shown on the image, it seems you're not good to go. The only thing I'm concerned with is that it also shows the use of European and non-european products but it isn't specified. Inshallah there will be nothing haram in it.

So, I'd say enjoy your new vegetarian pesto.  ;)
Apologies for the mistake. 
Sources:

https://islamqa.info/en/114129
https://islamqa.info/en/219137
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grana_Padano
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucono_delta-lactone
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecorino_Romano
https://www.cheesemaking.com/learn/faq/rennet.html

L.S.:
If you want to get more info about the etiquette of eating in islam, feel free to go to the link below.

https://islamqa.info/en/13348

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it helped you. I spent quite some time reading the articles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the research & efforts towards guiding me to this. Im relieved a bit as its quite yummy. However, alhumdulillah, I already found another pesto which is vegan safe :) Thanks again & jazakAllah khair.

Comment: Ameen. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Your answer does not take into consideration that cheese is made by using [rennet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennet), which is extracted from slaughtered animals. If the animal is halal and slaughtered by dhabiha then the cheese would be halal, if the animal is maitah (not slaughtered by dhabiha) then there is difference of opinion on whether it is halal. If the animal is inherently not halal (e.g. pig) then the cheese is not halal.

Comment: I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Filippo Berio regarding the non-vegetarian cheese & here is their reply:

> We use Pecorino Romano Cheese and Grana Padano in our pesto’s which
>   both contain animal rennet. Therefore our pesto’s are not vegetarian.

According to [10 things to know about rennet](http://Indeed,%20rennet%20is%20extracted%20from%20the%20lining%20of%20the%20inside%20of%20the%20stomach%20of%20mammals,%20and%20most%20commonly%20from%20the%20fourth%20stomach%20of%20young%20calves.%203.%20Rennet%20contains%20enzymes%20that%20cause%20milk%20to%20become%20cheese,%20by%20separating%20it%20into%20the%20solid%20curds%20and%20the%20liquid%20whey.):

> Indeed, rennet is extracted from the lining of the inside of the
>   stomach of mammals, and most commonly from the fourth stomach of young
>   calves. 3. Rennet contains enzymes that cause milk to become cheese,
>   by separating it into the solid curds and the liquid whey.

I hope this helps.